# how to change the date format in jquery date picker?

Tags: php, jquery-ui-datepicker

Hi i am using an date picker on selecting a date the date is displayed in this format
month/date/year ....
   How to convert the date to this format year-month-date in date picker js itself

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1328025/jquery-ui-datepicker-change-date-format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Date.firstDayOfWeek = 0;
    Date.format = 'yyyy-mm-dd';
    $(function()
    {
        $('.date-pick').datePicker()
    });

Answer (score 1):

This will apply the date format to all datepickers that are created after:

```
$.datepicker.setDefaults({
    dateFormat: 'dd.mm.yy'
});
```

Or to apply to a specific datepicker:

```
$('#selector').datepicker({
    dateFormat: 'dd.mm.yy'
});
```