# jquery date picker get date string in dd/mm/yy

Tags: jquery, string, date, get

I have the string

'Thu Oct 20 2011 00:00:00 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)'

and would like to get date in format dd/mm/yyyy out of this. How can I do this using jquery date picker library?

Answer (score 22):

This is a dupe question asked here before:
[jQuery UI DatePicker - Change Date Format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1328025/jquery-ui-datepicker-change-date-format)

You can do this:

```
$( ".selector" ).datepicker({ dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd' }).val();
```

Just to note though, the [JqueryUIDatePicker](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/) has a [formatdate](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Datepicker/formatDate) and [parseDate](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Datepicker/parseDate) function too.

Answer (score 19):

You can use the **javascript Date()** method

```
var dateTime = new Date($("#yourSelector").datepicker("getDate"));

var strDateTime =  dateTime.getDate() + "/" + (dateTime.getMonth()+1) + "/" + dateTime.getFullYear();

console.log(strDateTime);
```

Comment: I like this answer because it will work even if you don't have an input related to the datepicker like if it is set on a DIV.

Comment: Why `dateTime.getMonth()+1` ?

Comment: getMonth() method returns the month from 0 to 11

Answer (score 7):

If you already set dateFormat parameter in datepicker initiation, you may use only

```
    $( ".selector" ).val();
```

Because, else, using :

```
    $( ".selector" ).datepicker({ dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd' }).val();
```

is causing datepicker's onSelect event not to be triggered (don't know why, just observed).

Answer (score 2):

try having a look at http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Datepicker/formatDate

Answer (score 2):

Initialize a datepicker with the dateFormat option specified.

```
$( ".selector" ).datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yyyy' });
```

Get or set the dateFormat option, after init.

```
//getter
var dateFormat = $( ".selector" ).datepicker( "option", "dateFormat" );
//setter
$( ".selector" ).datepicker( "option", "dateFormat", 'dd/mm/yyyy' );
```

Answer (score 0):

set your datepicker with dateFormat

```
$( ".selector" ).datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yyyy' });
```

Then onSelect function of datepicker try below

```
$('#datepicker').datepicker({           
        dateFormat: "dd/mm/yyyy",
        onSelect: function () {               
            $(this).val(); //this will return the date ex: 29/07/2019

        }
    });
```