# Change date format in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I keep looking for steps in the Internet on how I can change a format of a certain date

```
$j("#activitycalendar").datepicker("setDate", $j.datepicker.parseDate("yy-mm-dd",$_GET.critval));
```

All I want to do is to set the date of a datepicker depending on what the `$_GET.critval` contains. And the `$_GET.critval` contains a date in this format

> 2011-12-05

as the jqueryui documents says

> "The new date may be a Date object or a string in the current date
>   format (e.g. '01/26/2009')" [jQuery UI - Datepicker Demos and Documentation](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#method-setDate)

so I wanted to change the format of my `$_GET.critval` so it can change the date of the datepicker. I tried the `$j.datepicker.parseDate` but it really doesn't work. the return value of that parsing will be like this

> Mon Dec 05 2011 00:00:00 GMT+0800 (Taipei Standard Time)

Is there any solution so I can format the date and set the date of the datepicker? thanks

Comment: This question has been answered

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1328025/jquery-ui-datepicker-change-date-format

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/)! It's a really powerful little library for working with Dates in JavaScript.

```
var today = moment(new Date());
today.format("YYYY-M-D");                  // "2012-4-11"
today.format("MMMM D, YYYY h:m A");        // outputs "April 11, 2012 2:40 PM"

// in one line...
moment().format("YYYY-M-D");               // "2012-4-11"
moment().format("MMMM D, YYYY h:m A");     // outputs "April 11, 2012 2:40 PM"
```

Another example...

```
var a = moment([2012, 2, 12, 15, 25, 50, 125]);
a.format("dddd, MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a"); // "Monday, March 12th 2012, 3:25:50 pm"
a.format("ddd, hA");                       // "Mon, 3PM"
```

---

Also, its worth mentioning to checkout [date.js](http://www.datejs.com/). I think the two libraries complement each other.