# Jquery datepicker format date not working

Tags: jquery, datepicker

Here is my code:

```
$(function () {
    $("#datepicker").datepicker({ dateFormat: 'DD-MM-YY' });
});
```

And the datetime picker is shown, but in format mm/dd/yyyy. Why is it not working?

Comment: have u seen this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1328025/jquery-ui-datepicker-change-date-format/1328040?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

try out this

```
$(".datepicker").datepicker({dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy'});
```

small letter will works

Answer (score 32):

Try just **format** option not **dateFormat**

```
$('#datepicker').datepicker({
   format: 'dd-mm-yyyy' 
});
```

Comment: you saved me also. Cheers!

Comment: This is working. Try just format option not dateFormat. Because due to different version of datepicker.

Comment: Thanks, dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy' is not working in my code. Format is working

Comment: Thanks. Everywhere, it is shown as "dateformat" in examples.

Answer (score 15):

Depending on the version of datepicker being used, the correct format may be:

```
$('#datepicker').datepicker({ format: 'yyyy-mm-dd' });
```

Answer (score 12):

Thats the default, meaning it does not recognise your option.

try:

```
dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy'
```

(small letters)

Comment: It's confusing but "yy" actually gives you the 4-digit year.

Comment: Depends which datepicker, and which distribution of it.  Different ones use different meanings for upper and lower case y, and d.  Everyone wants to re-invent everything for their "special" version, instead of sticking with the strftime standard.  And is it "format" or dateFormat?  Just keep piddling and fiddling until you "discover" what the particular author thought was the "cooler way" to do it.

Comment: @JosephK totally that! The API docs are very clear that the property is "dateFormat", but after reading your comment I tried "format" and it started working. Oh, and for extra fun, I needed to use "yyyy" for a four-digit date. Yeah, consistency FTW :-/

Comment: If you find "format" and using "yyyy" instead of "yy" is working for you, you may actually be using the bootstrap version of datepicker. Be sure to check your script src included .js files to see WHOSE datepicker you're using.

Answer (score 10):

Setting the default format will solve the problem, this solution works for me while all above do not.

```
$.datepicker.setDefaults({
     dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'
});
```

Source: [Datepicker: Adding dateFormat is giving an error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16974543/datepicker-adding-dateformat-is-giving-an-error/16974655#16974655)

Answer (score 3):

See this Jsfiddle link that is working example for me:

http://jsfiddle.net/nEGTv/3/

Answer (score 3):

Full example:

In jsp:

```
<div id="datepicker"></div>
```

In script:

```
function datepicker() {

  $("#datepicker").datepicker({
    showButtonPanel: true,
    dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
    onSelect: function() {
        var dateObject = $('#datepicker').datepicker().val();
        alert(dateObject);
    }
   }
  );
}
```

Answer (score 3):

this one works for me

```
$('#datepicker').datepicker({ format: 'dd-mm-yyyy' });
```

Answer (score 3):

If you're getting the default date value from your backend framework/service, i.e., `Asp.Net MVC`, setting the `dateFormat` when you initiate the `datepicker` on your input won't format the date initially.

```js
$(function() {
    $('#date-start').datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'mm/dd/yy',
        onSelect: function(startDate) {
            ...
        }
    });
});
```

[image]

The screenshot above shows, even I am initializing the input with a short date like `03/15/2018`, the `datepicker` won't pick up the format initially. All selections afterward would work as expected.

[image]

The fix is you have to set the `dateFormat` option manually after the `datepicker` initialization:

```js
$(function() {
    // $('#date-start').datepicker({
    //     dateFormat: 'mm/dd/yy',
    //     onSelect: function(startDate) {
    //         ...
    //     }
    // });
    // $('#date-start').datepicker('option', 'dateFormat', 'mm/dd/yy');

    // Or you can chain them
    $('#date-start').datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'mm/dd/yy',
        onSelect: function(startDate) {
            ...
        }
    }).datepicker('option', 'dateFormat', 'mm/dd/yy');
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$(function() {
    $('#datepicker').datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
    }).datepicker('option', 'dateFormat', 'dd/mm/yy');
});
```

It works 100%.

Comment: its really help when we have date range picker and datepicker-ui both in one screen.

Answer (score 2):

```
$('.datepicker').datepicker({
        format: 'dd-mm-yyyy',
        autoclose: true
    })
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing some additional context regarding how and why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Answer (score 1):

I had similar issue: `dateFormat` was set in defaults, but it did not work.

```js
$.App.Utils.DatePicker = {
  initialize: function(event) {
    $.datepicker.setDefaults({
      dateFormat: 'dd.mm.yy',
      firstDay: 1,
      changeMonth: true,
      changeYear: true,
      showOtherMonths: true,
      selectOtherMonths: true,
      showOn: 'both',
      buttonImage: '/assets/calendar.png',
      buttonImageOnly: true
    })
  },

activate: function(event) {
    this.initialize()
    $('input.datepicker').datepicker()
  }
```

But date was still displayed in default format, with slashes, like `02/03/2021`. Maybe this option can not be overwritten in defaults.

Working solution: remove `dateFormat` from `setDefaults` and set it when initializing datepicker:

```
activate: function(event) {
    this.initialize()
    $('input.datepicker').datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd.mm.yy' })
}
```

[Docs](https://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/)

Answer (score 0):

C#:-

```
 [Column(TypeName = "date")]
        [Display(Name = "Date of Birth")]
        [Required]
        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
        public DateTime? DOB { get; set; }
```

CSHTL:-

```
 @Html.EditorFor(model => model.DOB, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" , @required = "required", @autocomplete="off"} })

        $(document).ready(function () {
        var validationerror = false;
         $('input[type=date]').datepicker({
             dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
             changeMonth: true,
             changeYear: true,
             yearRange: "-60:+0"
         });
```