# not able to format date using jquery datepicker

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

I am invoking the datepicker on an input box. However, irrespective of the format I am giving, it always returns the date in mm/dd/yyyy format. I want it to return - 30-11-2011 (dd-mm-yyyy) format. Below are the options I tried -

**Option 1**

```
$("#birthdate").datepicker({
    changeYear: true,
    changeMonth: true
    dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'
    });
```

**Option 2**

```
$.datepicker.formatDate('yy-mm-dd', new Date(2007, 1 - 1, 26));
```

My html includes jquery-ui.js, jquery-ui-datepicker.js and jquery.js.

I have already referred to [jQuery UI DatePicker - Change Date Format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1328025/jquery-ui-datepicker-change-date-format/1328040)  and [Jquery datepicker format date not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9888000/jquery-datepicker-format-date-not-working)   and tried all the option but none of them in working for me. Please let me know if someone knows the solution.

Comment: Option 1) is missing a comma. Have you tried:

$("#birthdate").datepicker({ changeYear: true, changeMonth: true, dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd' });

Comment: comma is somehow missed while pasting the code, but it doesn't work with comma as well.

Comment: You are loading jquery-ui AND jquery-ui-datepicker? I use this widget a lot and have not had trouble with date formatting. It's possible that including both of these files is what is at fault?

Comment: wow ! removing jquery-ui.js worked. Thank you so much !

Comment: @adhiran: I posted my answer you indicated was the solution to your problem. Please mark this question answered. Thanks!