# jquery datepicker dateFormat not working

Tags: jquery, date, datepicker

I can't get it to accept an input, it's just going to the default of mm/dd/yyyy.

```
$('.customDate').datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy' }).mask('99/99/9999');
```

I've tried 'dd-mm-yy' and 'dd-mm-yyyy' with no luck. I've read the documentation.

There are elements with the given class, I checked. The mask is working. All files are present.

That line is the last line in my:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
});
```

Comment: The mask plugin is probably overriding the datepicker. Why are you using different formats?

Comment: To add, there are no console errors stopping script execution.

Comment: Barmar, I'm not, 'yy' is actually a 4 digit year as per the documentation.https://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#utility-formatDate

Comment: But your mask has `/` while `dateFormat` has `-`.

Comment: Same result after changing to "/" for both. The delimiter in the formatDate is not what actually sets the delimiter.

Comment: Can you make an executable stack snippet that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: It works in a jsfiddle. :/ https://jsfiddle.net/f026rjqc/

Comment: Then something else must be going on in your application. If you can't provide enough to demonstrate the problem, it will be hard for us to figure out what's wrong.

Answer (score 1):

It was a versioning issue. I updated to the latest version of jquery.datepicker and it worked.

For anyone who comes across this question, this was the end result:

```
$('.customDate').datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy' }).mask('99/99/9999');
```

Comment: `dateFormat` has worked for years, I don't see how it could be because you were using an old version. Maybe an incompatibility between versions of jQuery and jQuery UI?

Comment: And you say dateFormat has worked for years, however this post, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9888000/jquery-datepicker-format-date-not-working, shows differently.

Comment: He gave an incorrect format, using uppercase instead of lowercase. Why does that mean it doesn't work?

Comment: I take it you didn't read the comments. He had to use format, not dateFormat, to get it to work despite the documentation stating dateFormat is the correct option.

Comment: That was someone else, not the person who posted the question. My guess is he wasn't using jQuery UI Datepicker, but some other datepicker library with different options.