# jquery ui datepicker datatables

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker, datatables

hi i am using the datatables plugin and date range filter out want. The problem is that the dates That I have them in this **format**: **dd / mm / yyyy H: i: s** in the table. When I give to filter out the **dialog datapicker** but I put the **H: i: s** any way to do?

http://jquery-datatables-column-filter.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/dateRange.html

Another question I have that as change the words From: and To: to display them in my language.

Comment: checkout with jquery-ui demo(jquery-ui-1.9.0.custom/development-bundle/demos/datepicker/date-formats.html), i hope your solution is there.

Comment: datepicker plugin does not work with hours. thanks

Comment: so you want time also. go for time picker addon for jquery. http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/

Answer (score 0):

Use a format in jquery time picker / datepicker that matches your database. Use these code for converting the datepicker for mysql

```
$.datepicker.regional[""].dateFormat = 'yy-mm-dd';
$.datepicker.setDefaults($.datepicker.regional['']);
```

You will have to use similar thing for the time picker

Answer (score 0):

You should use something like this:

```
var date = $('#datepicker').datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy' }).val();
```

Reference: [jQuery UI DatePicker - Change Date Format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1328025/jquery-ui-datepicker-change-date-format?rq=1)