# Change jQuery datepicker date format

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker, date-format

I am using jQuery datepicker. I have bound a `Textbox` with `Datepicker`. I want to change the date format so that it displays dates like `Tuesday, 29 - Jan - 2013`. How can I do that ?

Comment: http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-dateFormat

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery UI DatePicker - Change Date Format](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1328025/jquery-ui-datepicker-change-date-format)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

```
$( ".selector" ).datepicker({ dateFormat: 'DD, d-M-yy' });
```

http://jqueryui.com/resources/demos/datepicker/date-formats.html

Answer (score 0):

I think it was already posted here:

Try out this one:

[jQuery UI DatePicker - Change Date Format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1328025/jquery-ui-datepicker-change-date-format)

Answer (score 0):

You have to use  the date format options to format date [[link]](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Datepicker/formatDate)

```
$(document).ready(function () {  

               var pickerOpts = {
                dateFormat:"DD ,d - M  yy"
               };  
              $("#fromDate").datepicker(pickerOpts);     

            });
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/muthusamy/CchjW/7/)