# jQuery UI Datepicker and Rails doesn't play along?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, jquery-ui, datepicker

I'm using Rails 3.2 and the jQuery datepicker.

Problem is I can't get any of the formatting/customisations to work.

My code in posts.js.coffee:

```
    jQuery ->
     $('#post_date').datepicker()
     dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy"
     minDate: "1w"
```

If I test it at http://jsfiddle.net/y2wgK/ everything works fine.
I tried plain Java script as well. Same thing happens. Rails ignores everything except the date picker.In other words, the datepicker works fine, but for every utility function like maxdate, mindate, dateFormat nothing happens.

Please tell me what am I missing?

Comment: Would you go into further detail on: "Rails ignores everything except the date picker." ?

Comment: I updated the details. Pretty simple.

Comment: How is this different from your other question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16130815/how-to-change-the-date-formatting-with-jquery-ui-datepicker-and-rails?

Comment: It was supposed to be more specific. Your welcome to delete it.

Answer (score 0):

The Coffee script should be (see brackets):

```
  $('#post_date').datepicker (dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy')
```

I don't know how the Railscasts #213 Calendars (revised) works, because Ryan doesn't use the brackets at all.