# Jquery UI Datepicker re-formatting formated date

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-datepicker

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(function(){
    $('.vDateField').datepicker();
    $('.vDateField').datepicker( "option", "dateFormat", 'dd/mm/yy' );  
});             
</script>
```

I have a date field which uses a datepicker to select a date in dd/mm/yy format. This works great for the initial page submit, but when the page is reloaded with the selected date pre-populated in the date field.. datepicker is formatting it again it seems. It is swapping the days and months around so if the user enteres 02/05/2013 the calender date field would show 05/02/2013 when the page has reloaded.

The date going through to the server is fine, it's just when the page has reloaded the pre-populated date field has been reformatted.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1328025/2128691

Comment: check what what is format for pre-populated date, i guess that you might to format that date too

Comment: Are you using MVC jquery validate or some other kind of serverside client validation?