# Change jquery date picker format

Tags: jquery

Hello Following is jquery date picker code. It's showing date following format:

```
day/month/year
```

How do i change this format to that format ?

```
day-month-year
```

**Complete Jquery Code:**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>jQuery UI Datepicker - Default functionality</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
<script>
$(function() {
$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker"></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-dateFormat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a lot of post about that topic.

```
var date = $('#datepicker').datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy' }).val();
```

More general info available here:

[jQuery UI DatePicker - Change Date Format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1328025/jquery-ui-datepicker-change-date-format)