# datepicker change date format on form submit

Tags: jquery, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker, date-format

I am using jQuery datepicker, and I am displaying my date in

> dd-mm-yyyy

format but I need to send date in

> yyyy-mm-dd

format to store in database.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.datepicker').datepicker({
        format : 'dd-mm-yyyy',
        maxDate : new Date(),
        selectMonths : true,
        selectYears: d,
        yearRange: 100 ,
    }); 
});
```

the above code will show date format

> dd-mm-yy

and when I submit the form using ajax, it sends using this same format. I need to change the submit format to

> yyyy-mm-dd

Check this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/prashanthviru/b42dzwLb/).

Comment: Dont store dates as strings, store them as date type.

Comment: If you want to add code to your question then edit it

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change jquery date picker format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21334915/change-jquery-date-picker-format)

Comment: If your database is storing dates in a column of type `string`, rather than of type `date`, then you will save yourself a lot of pain if you just migrate the column to the `date` type. However, we realise this might not be possible, if someone else in in charge of the database schema, if the system is already in place, or if the DB is accessed through a stringly-typed protocol. (@musefan)

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/prashanthviru/b42dzwLb/  check this fiddle  in alert my idea is to alert in yyyy-mm-dd format so fiddle me code

Answer (score 0):

Please try this to get the value

```
 $("#mydate").datepicker("option", "dateFormat", "yyyy-mm-dd" ).val();
```

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/prashanthviru/b42dzwLb/  check this fiddle  in alert my idea is to alert in yyyy-mm-dd format so fiddle me code

Comment: you need to add date picker js and css

Comment: its working now ..please check https://jsfiddle.net/prashanthviru/b42dzwLb/

Comment: alert must be in yyy-mm-dd format check fiddle it alert in dd-mm-yyyy format only

Comment: please check now  @Prashanthv its done https://jsfiddle.net/prashanthviru/b42dzwLb/

Comment: no its not working plz check it again alert in  dd-mm-yyyy i need alert in yyyy-mm-dd format @madhu Nair

Comment: `code function GetFormattedDate(mydate) {
var fields = mydate.split('-');

var day = fields[0];
var month = fields[1];
var year = fields[2];


abc= year +-+month+-+day;

return abc
}` place this and pass the value the result is your desired one

Comment: thanks @madhu one more problem i have multiple form in site so iam calling same datepicker so  i need to know that multiple script must be include ? r can use common script to all forms and iam also submiting form in ajax submit and serialize data so how to do with this