# convert mysql date to datetimepicker

Tags: jquery, mysql, datepicker

I want to convert mysql date to datetimepicker, because datetimepicker has different format from mysql and this makes the datepicker readonly and I can't select another date.

```
$(function() {
        $('#date').datetimepicker({
            pickTime: false,
        });
    });

mysql: y-m-d
datetimepicker:mm/dd/yy
```

**EDIT**
controller

```
 public function edit($id) {
        $values = DB::table('insur_docs')->where('car_id', $id)->get();
        return View::make('pages.insur_docs', array(
                    'values' => $values,
        ));
```

view

```
{{ Form::label('authoriz', Lang::get('messages.authorization').'*', array('class'=>'control-label col-lg-4')) }}            
                <div class="col-lg-8">
                    {{ Form::text ('authoriz', isset($v->authoriz) ? $v->authoriz : '' , array(
                                'class' => 'form-control', 'id' => 'date')) 
                    }}
                </div>
```

I get data from controller and pass to the view

Answer (score 0):

Change the format of the dateTime picker like so:

```
$(function() {
        $('#date').datetimepicker({
            dateFormat: 'mm/dd/yy'
        });
    });
```

Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1328040/1691423) SO.

Comment: From where do you get your data? How are u passing it to you date picker?

Comment: just edited my question, i get date from controller pass to the view and it displays it as mysql format. In this way datepicker doesnt select any value because the change in format

Comment: can you post the html code which this php (I believe laravel) producing, just copy & paste the relevant part of the page source.