# how do i get the date format in Date-month-year format from jquery UI date picker?

Tags: jquery, date

```
 $( "#datepicker1, #datepicker2" ).datepicker(
 {dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy'}).val();
           and
$( "#datepicker1, #datepicker2" ).datepicker('option', 'dateFormat', 'dd-mm-yy');


<div class="date1"> 
  <label>From Date :</label>                       
  <input type="text" required="" placeholder="Select From Date" name="fromdate1" id="datepicker1">          
</div>
<div class="date1">  
  <label>To Date :</label>                       
  <input type="text" required="" placeholder="Select To Date" name="todate1" id="datepicker2">                 
</div>
```

When i'm using the above code,it shows the date in **12/16/2013** format.How do i get the date in **16/12/2013** ? Kindly do me a favour.

Answer (score 1):

Try this [Stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1328025/jquery-ui-datepicker-change-date-format) question

```
var date = $('#datepicker').datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy' }).val();
```

More general info available here:

- http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-dateFormat
- http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#utility-formatDate

Comment: If you find a similar question on stack overflow, please mark it as duplicate rather then sharing the link of question and posting it as answer.

Comment: sorry i'm getting the same result...i didn't get my desired format

Comment: var pickerOpts = {
           dateFormat:"dd/mm/yy"
       }; 
$( "#datepicker1" ).datepicker(pickerOpts);
var pickerOpts1 = {
           dateFormat:"dd/mm/yy"
       };  $( "#datepicker2" ).datepicker(pickerOpts1);
i can convert it by using the above code.... :)