# Converting date format from mm/dd/yyyy to yyyy-mm-dd format after entered

Tags: javascript

In my datepicker the date will be inserted in mm/dd/yyyy format. But after I inserted I want it to be sent in yyyy-mm-dd format. I am using JavaScript to do this. But I wasn't able to do that. So what should I do?

Thanks & regards,
Chiranthaka

Comment: Please show us what you've tried.

Comment: This is what I have tried    $("#to_date, #from_date").datepicker({maxDate: new Date(),dateFormat:'yyyy-mm-dd'});                                                           But in here the date pass as 20142014-07-10. It duplicates the year. If I change it to yy-mm-dd it pass the date as 2014-07-10. This is what I want.   But when I use this within Google Analytics Dashboard it gives me an error regarding using regular expressions. It means the date format is not identified as the correct format. So what do you think about that?

Comment: The source code I have used <code>  $("#to_date, #from_date").datepicker({maxDate: new Date(),dateFormat:'yyyy-mm-dd'}); </code>

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1328025/jquery-ui-datepicker-change-date-format
Based on this SO question, I used datepicker formatDate to get the format of yyyy-mm-dd:

dateObject = $('#datepicker').datepicker('getDate');
var dateString = $.datepicker.formatDate('yy-mm-dd', dateObject); 

Note that the format specifier only uses yy to get the four-digit date, eg 2017-02-07
When I used yyyy, I got the year twice, as in 20172017-02-07

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you could also use regular expressions:

```
var convertDate = function(usDate) {
  var dateParts = usDate.split(/(\d{1,2})\/(\d{1,2})\/(\d{4})/);
  return dateParts[3] + "-" + dateParts[1] + "-" + dateParts[2];
}

var inDate = "12/06/2013";
var outDate = convertDate(inDate); // 2013-12-06
```

The expression also works for single digit months and days.

Answer (score 1):

I did the opposite for my website, but it might help you. I let you modify it in order to fit your requierements. Have fun !

[getDate](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_getdate.asp)

[getMonth](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_getmonth.asp)

[getFullYear](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_getfullyear.asp)

Have fun on [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp)

```
var d = new Date();
var curr_date = d.getDate();
var curr_month = d.getMonth() + 1; //Months are zero based
var curr_year = d.getFullYear();

if(curr_month < 10)
curr_month = "0"+curr_month;
if(curr_date < 10)
curr_date = "0"+curr_date;
var curr_date_format = curr_date+"/"+curr_month+"/"+curr_year;
```

Comment: I am using JQuery date picker to insert dates. So what should I do?

Comment: I guess fill up http://jsfiddle.net/ and check out http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#method-getDate . Or I haven't fully understood what you're trying to do.

Comment: This is not about entering the current date pal. This is about entering date in mm/dd/yyyy format but it should deliver to the corresponding function as yyyy-mm-yy format. Because Google Analytics supports only supports that format.

Answer (score 0):

Adding more to Christof R's solution (thanks! used it!) to allow for MM-DD-YYYY (- in addition to /) and even MM DD YYYY. Slight change in the regex.

```
var convertDate = function(usDate) {
  var dateParts = usDate.split(/(\d{1,2})[\/ -](\d{1,2})[\/ -](\d{4})/);
  return dateParts[3] + "-" + dateParts[1] + "-" + dateParts[2];
}

var inDate = "12/06/2013";
var outDate = convertDate(inDate); // 2013-12-06
```

As Christof R says: This also works for single digit day and month as well.

Answer (score -1):

```
 // format from M/D/YYYY to YYYYMMDD
 Date.prototype.yyyymmdd = function() {
    var yyyy = this.getFullYear();
    var mm = this.getMonth() < 9 ? "0" + (this.getMonth() + 1) : (this.getMonth() + 1); // getMonth() is zero-based
    var dd = this.getDate() < 10 ? "0" + this.getDate() : this.getDate();
    return "".concat(yyyy).concat(mm).concat(dd);
  };

var siku = new Date();
document.getElementById("day").innerHTML = siku.yyyymmdd();
```

Comment: While this might be a valuable hint to solve the problem, a good answer also demonstrates the solution. Please [EDIT](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/59628321/edit) to provide example code to show what you mean. Alternatively, consider writing this as a comment instead