# Formating date on Jquery UI datapicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, datapicker

I'm having troubles on formating the dates on Jquery UI datapicker.

What I have to do is choose a date on the calendar UI and then I have to calculate some dates based on the date entered. Everything is working except for the date format. Is showing me the FULL date as follows: "Mon Sep 15 2014 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (Hora de verano romance)" and I just want a dd-mm-yy format

check it here http://fiddle.jshell.net/80em5wLd/

```
<input type="text" name="arrivalDate" class="datepicker">
<input type="" name="auditDate" value="">
<input type="" name="presentationDate" value="">

 $('input[name="arrivalDate"]').datepicker({
 onSelect: function(){
 var start = $('input[name="arrivalDate"]').val();

 var audit= 14;
 var presentation= audit+14;
 var date = new Date(start);
 var d = date.getDate();
 var m = date.getMonth();
 var y = date.getFullYear();
 var date_1= new Date (y, m, d+audit);
 var date_2= new Date(y, m, d+presentation);
 $('input[name="auditDate"]').val(date_1);
 $('input[name="presentationDate"]').val(date_2);
}
```

});

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1328025/jquery-ui-datepicker-change-date-format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have this a try, `date.toLocaleDateString();`

Comment: Thanks this is it! I just needed to add it to the new date variable and it totally worked thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy' })
```

Comment: and this way ? 

var date = $('#datepicker').datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy' }).val();

Comment: Adding the dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy' is screwing the dates and not changing the format.. check out the example http://fiddle.jshell.net/80em5wLd/