# Date format Datepicker jQuery ui

Tags: jquery, datepicker

I have a DatePicker field, I would like it to show this format : 'M d', but I want the value of this date in this date format 'yy-mm-dd'.

Is there a way to show a date format and submitted another one ?

Here my DatePicker fonction

```
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
                dateFormat: \'yy-mm-dd\',   
                buttonImage: \'calendar.png\',   
                buttonImageOnly: true,   
                showOn: \'button\',   
   });
```

Here my field

```
<input type="text" name="simulateur[startingDate]" id="datepicker" required>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery UI DatePicker - Change Date Format](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1328025/jquery-ui-datepicker-change-date-format)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this using **altFormat** and **altField** properties of datepicker.

Suppose you are having two inputs, one is for displaying your required date and other for holding date value of format as "yy-mm-dd"

```
<input type="text" name="begin-date" id="begin-date" value="" />
<input type="text" id="alt-date" />
```

Apply js as:

```
$("#begin-date").datepicker({   
  dateFormat: "M d",
  altFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
  altField: "#alt-date"
});
```

Then first input will show date in "M d" format and second one show in "yy-mm-dd" format, as per your requirements :)

Please **[refer to fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Mazzu/fyv33/981/)** for same.

Comment: Thats perfect. Actually, is it possible to divide the date "M d" to show it in two different input ? Like one input with the month, and one input with the day ? Like that I can stylize the month and the day differently.

Answer (score 0):

You can try it using altField/AltFormat options:

http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-altField
http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-altFormat