# Available Datepicker for jQuery v 1.10.2

Tags: jquery

Goal:
I'm looking for a datepicker for a website.

Question:
I cannot select any datepicker because I'm using jquery-1.10.2.

Do you know any datepicker that use jquery-1.10.2.?
It is only enough to retrieve the dates only.

Information:
*Unfortunatley, I cannot upgrade the jquery because the end users are using old web browser.
*I'm using ASP.net MVC and Bootstrap v1.6.3

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: I don't understand why jQuery 1.10 would prevent you from using any datepickers.

Comment: I don't understand, you telling me that any datepicker works to use even if they recommend this specific datepicker to use jquery 1.7?

Comment: Well, yes, unless they specifically say that it won't work on anything newer. Have you actually tried it? And if it doesn't work, surely if you google for "jquery datepicker" you'll get literally dozens of other choices to try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"I cannot select any datepicker because I'm using jquery-1.10.2", Unfortunately thats not right.
It definitely works! Please follow the below snippet.

```js
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#foo").datepicker();
});
```

```html
 <!-- Load jQuery UI CSS  -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
<!-- Load jQuery JS -->
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Load jQuery UI Main JS  -->
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <input type="text" id="foo" />
  
  </body>
```

Comment: If I understand, in order to use datepicker it is almost compulsory to use jQuery UI, is it true?

Comment: Now why the hell was that a minus? Any explanations from the concerned folk here.

Comment: Don't ask me. I raised it with "+"

Comment: "If I understand, in order to use datepicker it is almost compulsory to use jQuery UI, is it true?", yeah thats true!

Comment: No, it's certainly not true. There are many datepickers that don't rely on jQuery UI.

Comment: Juhana - Any suggestion?

Comment: Sudhansu - Do you have the website that you have retrieve the datepicker? I also gonna need to change the date into yyyymmdd and the first day should display monday instead of sunday.

Comment: [Try any of these](https://www.google.com/search?q=jquery+datepicker+-"jquery+ui")

Comment: @HelloWorld this might help you, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1328025/jquery-ui-datepicker-change-date-format.