# Apply .js file for required control only in mvc

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc-4, datepicker

I have one  mvc application and i created one form, In this form i use textbox for datepicker and file input control for pickup the picture. 
 this is my browse button for picture,
[image]

I used this js file for file input

```
 <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

and i used this js file for datepicker

```
<script src="../../Scripts/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
```

Now, my problem is that for my datepicker i used same jquery file but different version. due to this datepicker js file and this second js file is overlapping.. and my datepicker is not working correctly. so is this possible if above 1st mentioned js file will apply for input file tag only , not for other controls on same page....????

Comment: which version of jquery is the first file? Use a single version of jquery and include jqueryUI.min.js file as well for datepicker.

Comment: please can you describe in brief ....????

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31100046/available-datepicker-for-jquery-v-1-10-2/31100209#31100209 use the dependencies mentioned there

Comment: you didn answer which version of jquery is the first file?? You can use the same version's jqueryUI, as in the above link I shared the version is 1.10.2 for both jquery and jqueryUI

Comment: i don't know version of first file, there is not mentioned related to version...

Comment: remove that file and use the ones mentioned in my answer, I mean in the link that I shared. Did you run that snippet on that link?

Comment: yes  i did, i removed both js files and add that three files which are you mentioned in your answer. but now my datepicker is working correctly but input file tag is not......

Comment: set up a jsfiddler at jsfiddler.net. Add your original code there, the one from where the problem started

Comment: Not satisfied...... tell mi can i apply that second first js for specific div and not for others....????

Comment: I told you to setup a fidler! where did the question of satisfaction come from? I'm not satisfied with what prob statement you have.. I don't see any code, nothing.. I don't understand your latest comment!!

Comment: ok, i tried to setup a fildler .. but i didn't get solution...its mandatory to use both files, beacuse i want calendar in better view, and also my image picker file input in better view, only prob is that that 2 files are overlapping and datepicker is not working, there fore i asked you is this possible to use one file for one div only not for other div.....

Comment: I understand thats why I asked for a fiddler link, so that we can visit that link, make changes to your code or something and check/solve the issues

Comment: Sorry I meant fiddle not fiddler, a fiddle at jsfiddle.net