# Show current day in the title of jquery datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

How can I show current full date in the **title** of jquery datepicker like this :

`05 July 2015` because it show me just `July 2015`

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery UI DatePicker - Change Date Format](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1328025/jquery-ui-datepicker-change-date-format)

Comment: no i don't talk about the selected date after i click on a date i talk about just the date that is displayed in the header

Comment: That text is the name of the month currently displayed in the calendar. If you change that to be today's date, what would you expect to see when you navigate to a different month?

Comment: I have posted my answer, with a working example on codepen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I couldn't find a non-hacky way of doing it, but changing the defaults config to the text you want to show might do it for you:

```
var defaults = {
  monthNames: ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December' ]
};

var today = new Date();
var month = today.getMonth();
defaults.monthNames[month] = today.getDate() + ' ' +  defaults.monthNames[month];

$.datepicker.setDefaults(defaults);
```

Here is a working plnkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/gfp95VOchd4fhQOktIL3?p=preview

Comment: your answer is good for me because the current day show just in the current month but the day is wrong

Comment: You're right, changed my answer from today.getDay() (gets day of the week) to today.getDate() (gets day of the month). Also updated plunkr.

Answer (score 5):

You could use a function like this in *onSelect*

```
function showDateInTitle(picker) {
    var span = picker.dpDiv[0].querySelector('.ui-datepicker-day'),
        df, month;
    if (span === null) {
        month = picker.dpDiv[0].querySelector('.ui-datepicker-month');
        if (!month) return;
        span = document.createElement('span');
        span.setAttribute('class', 'ui-datepicker-day');
        df = document.createDocumentFragment();
        df.appendChild(span);
        df.appendChild(document.createTextNode('\u00a0'));
        month.parentNode.insertBefore(
            df,
            month
        );
    }
    span.textContent = picker.selectedDay;
}
```

Still looking through API for a handler for after the datepicker is shown before choice is made

---

You can implement an *afterShow* as [**described here**](http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/6885) with a slight modification to get the instance

```
$(function() {
    $.datepicker._updateDatepicker_original = $.datepicker._updateDatepicker;
    $.datepicker._updateDatepicker = function(inst) {
        $.datepicker._updateDatepicker_original(inst);
        var afterShow = this._get(inst, 'afterShow');
        if (afterShow)
            afterShow.apply((inst.input ? inst.input[0] : null), [inst]);
    }
});
```

Now [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/jn09khj5/)

Comment: I hardly see why the thread starter has this weird need. I have answered to this question as well, but after seeing your answer, i realized that you took the better approach by taking advantage of the datepicker built in onSelect function. Thumbs up.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my solution, it is a simple jquery solution that append the day value to the current datepicker widget.

```
$('#datepicker').click(function(){
  var $datePickerBox = $('#ui-datepicker-div'); 
  //var $datePickerBox = $(this).closest('.ui-datepicker.ui-widget'); 
  var $monthName = $datePickerBox.find('.ui-datepicker-month');
  var currentDay = '';
  if($(this).val().trim().length==0){
    currentDay = $datePickerBox.find('.ui-datepicker-today').text();
  } else {
    currentDay = $datePickerBox.find('.ui-datepicker-current-day').text();
  }
  $monthName.text( currentDay + " " + $monthName.text() );
});
```

Code pen link
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/WvzKJo

Answer (score 1):

If you want to always show the current date at the top and not the selected date, using @PaulS.'s code change

```
span.textContent = picker.selectedDay;
```

to

```
span.textContent = new Date().getDate();
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/depperm/5mdztsaL/)