# IgniteUI: Select date and time from UI and pass it to ajax call as parameter

Tags: ajax, datetimepicker, ignite-ui

I want to select date and time in the format `yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss` from UI and pass the same as parameters to REST POST call using ajax.

I am using IgniteUI.

Please help me how to use `igDatePicker` for given format.

I have tried the basic example as shown below:

```
<html>
<head>
<style> 
    @media all and (max-width: 360px) { 
        .ui-datepicker { width: 250px; } 
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <input id="datePicker" type="date" /> 
    <script> 
        $(function () { $("#datePicker").igDatePicker(); }); 
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

My doubt is, it gives date and time in `yyyy/mm/dd hh:mm AM` format. Where can I edit the format to get `hh:mm:ss` time format?

The below code lets me select date and time in required format, but it gives the calender to select only data and with default time:

```
$('#datePicker').igDatePicker({ 
    width: width, 
    dateInputFormat: 'dateTime', 
    required: true, 
    validatorOptions: { 
        onblur: true, 
        onchange: false, 
        onsubmit: true, 
        formSubmit: true, 
        keepFocus: "always",
        showIcon: true 
    }
});
```

Any idea on how to use datepicker control tab even to select time? Does `IgniteUi` give such support to select time?

Comment: Try this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1328025/jquery-ui-datepicker-change-date-format

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please do not post additional information as comments when asked, simply edit in your question and provide all details. I edited your question to include the details from your comments. I also edited the title and several parts of your question to improve readability. Good luck!