# Change Date Format on jQuery UI Date Picker

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

I have been trying to format the datepicker so that the date comes out like this:

Jul 23 15

I have been reading this question [jQuery UI DatePicker - Change Date Format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1328025/jquery-ui-datepicker-change-date-format/1328040#1328040)

But for some reason it is not working for me. I am still learning jQuery so any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

My code is below:

```js
              $('input').datepicker({  
                
                          onSelect: function(dateText, inst) { 
                            var date = $(this).datepicker('getDate'),
                                day  = date.getDate(),  
                                month = date.getMonth() + 1,              
                                year =  date.getFullYear();
                            
                            var parent_div = $(this).closest(".clickable-text");
                            console.log(parent_div);
                            $(".Jquery_day", parent_div).html(day);
                            $(".Jquery_month", parent_div).html(month);
                            $(".Jquery_year", parent_div).html(year); 
                            $(parent_div).addClass("is_selected");   
                            


                        } 
                    });

                    $(window).load(function() {

                    $('input').datepicker();
                    $('input').datepicker("setDate", new Date());

                   var dateFormat = $('input').datepicker({dateFormat: "M-d-y"}).val();

                    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Updated snippet of code below:

```js
   $('input.start').datepicker({  

                                onSelect: function(dateText) {
                                  //  alert(dateText);
                                var date = $(this).datepicker('getDate'),
                                day  = date.getDate(),  
                                month = date.getMonth() + 1,              
                                year =  date.getFullYear();


                            var parent_div = $(this).closest(".clickable-text");
                            console.log(parent_div);
                            $(".Jquery_day", parent_div).html(day);
                            $(".Jquery_month", parent_div).html(month);
                            $(".Jquery_year", parent_div).html(year); 
                            $(parent_div).addClass("is_selected"); 

                             },
                                dateFormat: "M d y"
                            });

                         $('input.start').datepicker();
                         $('input.start').datepicker("setDate", new Date());
```

Please see jsfiddle below. It appears to work kind of okay here for some reason it is adding an extra calendar, it may be something else within my code that is causing the issue. If I am coding something wrong then please do let me know. I am struggling to get back the selected value on the 'Number of Adults' section as well but it seems to be working here.

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/chloe_12/qrxtqeza/)

Answer (score 0):

Were you after this?

```
$('input').datepicker({  

    onSelect: function(date) {
        alert(date);
    },
    dateFormat: "M d y"
});
```

Following are the allowed formats:

- Default:     `"mm/dd/yy"`
- ISO 8601:    `"yy-mm-dd"`
- Short:       `"d M, y"`
- Medium:      `"d MM, y"`
- Full:        `"DD, d MM, yy"`
- With text:   `"'day' d 'of' MM 'in the year' yy"`

[**A Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/gvwaaoxk/)

Comment: Thank you for your help, that has enabled me to progress a little further. Currently, there now seems to be another datepicker that is outputting at the bottom of the page (it is not in relation to the actual booking widget and has no effect on it).

Comment: That may be due to your selector, as, for now, `datepicker()` would be applied to all `input` elements on your page! May be, add a class to the booking related input, such as `"datepicker-bw"` and then do: `$('input.datepicker-bw').datepicker({.. `

Comment: Thanks for that. For some reason, I am still having the same issue! I appreciate your help.

Comment: Edit your question and post the updated code that you have at the moment.

Comment: I need to see your HTML as well, preferably, the code that replicates your issue, in a fiddle.

Comment: Please find demo above. Thank you.

Comment: Sure, I don't understand what the problem is. I see the date format working correctly.

Comment: I have made some updates to [your fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qrxtqeza/1/) as it's too much code for no reason. See if that's what you wanted.

Comment: Thank you for that. For some reason, there is still an extra datepicker showing outside of the widget at the bottom of the page which does not affect the widget at all. Currently trying to figure out why that is happening. Thank you for your help.