# Shield UI Datepicker, Format Selected value to dd/MM/yyy

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker, shieldui

I am using Shield UI Date picker for capturing DOB, I am facing problem in formatting the selected date. The JavaScript code I had used is shown below

```
$("#dobPicker").shieldDatePicker({
    openOnFocus: true,
    format: "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}",
    textTemplate: "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}",
    parseFormats: ["dd/MM/yyyy"],
    max: new Date(),
    events: {
        change: function(e) {
            var dobVal = $("#dobPicker").swidget().value();
            alert(dobVal);
        }
    }
});
```

And the output I got is in the below format

**Thu Aug 20 2015 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)**

But I require an out put in **dd/MM/yyyy format**

Could you help me to solve this?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1328025/jquery-ui-datepicker-change-date-format

Comment: @AbhishekGhosh I was searching for any inbuilt way to get that formatted value from my plugin(Shield UI). Thanks for the reply :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can parse the date as a standard date and format it any way you want.

Once you get the [value](http://shieldui.com/documentation/datepicker/javascript/api/methods/value), you can parse it and format it as needed. 
This is demonstrated [here](https://jsbin.com/lihovelexi/3/edit?html,output).

Comment: Thanks David for the detailed reply. Hope this will work for me.

Answer (score 0):

[Moment](http://momentjs.com/) you can use. This is great library for handling date. [CDN LINK](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.10.6/moment.min.js) for your use or you can download also.

```
var dobVal = new Date();
console.log(dobVal);//output Sat Aug 22 2015 20:24:10 GMT+0530 (IST)
var formatted = moment(dobVal).format("DD/MM/YYYY");
console.log(formatted);//output 22/08/2015
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/hmgymf77/)

Comment: Thanks for the reply :) I was searching for is there any inbuilt method to get that formatted value from the plugin Shield UI