# jQuery datepicker default format not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, jquery-ui-datepicker

This is what I have in my .js file:

```
var ready;
ready = function () {
    $.datepicker.setDefaults({
        dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'
    });
};
$(document).ready(ready);
```

But datepicker format is still the default: mm/dd/yy

Background: 
- I'm on Ruby on Rails
- also using bootstrap-datepicker-rails gem. Is there a conflict?

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1328025/jquery-ui-datepicker-change-date-format

Comment: You'll need to call the function, just defining it doesn't cause it to be run. You can add `()` to the end of it's definition to run it, but it would probably be better to not run it until the document is ready. `$(function() { your code });`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be possible that your code is being run after the datepicker is already initialized. You should be able to pass the `dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd"` option in wherever your datepicker is being initialized in your JavaScript.

You should be able to update the dateFormat after it's been initialized (based on [these docs](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-dateFormat)) like this:

```
// Setter
$(".selector").datepicker("option", "dateFormat", "yy-mm-dd");
```

`.selector` is most likely `.datepicker` in your case unless you've changed it (going of the [examples here](https://github.com/Nerian/bootstrap-datepicker-rails)).

Also, you should be able to see what the date format is set to like this:

```
console.log("dateFormat:", $(".selector").datepicker("option", "dateFormat"));
```

Answer (score 1):

Took a quick look into [jQuery Datepicker api documentation](https://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-dateFormat) and I found out you can do this

```
$( ".selector" ).datepicker({ dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd" });
```

Answer (score 0):

try like this:

```
$.extend($.fn.datepicker.defaults, {
    format:'yyyy-mm-dd',
    autoclose: true,
    todayHighlight: true,
    showOnFocus: false
});
```