# jQuery Datepicker date format not working

Tags: jquery, html, datepicker

I cannot seem to get the date format 'yyyy/mm/dd' to work in Datepicker - I have tried all the "solutions" out there, and the **only** thing that has worked for me so far is [this](https://jqueryui.com/resources/demos/datepicker/date-formats.html). But as you can see, it is a drop-down menu, and I do nor want to choose the format every time - I just want it to *be* that way.

Now, the linked script does it like this:

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
        $( "#format" ).change(function() {
            $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker( "option", "dateFormat", $( this ).val() );
        });
    });
</script>
```

Dropdown:

```
<option value="yy-mm-dd">ISO 8601 - yy-mm-dd</option>
```

I am *not* very good with jQuery, so I have absolutly no clue how to "convert".

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery UI DatePicker - Change Date Format](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1328025/jquery-ui-datepicker-change-date-format)

Comment: try `yy-MM-dd` as no-caps `mm` means minutes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$(function() {
    $("#datepicker").datepicker({ 
            dateFormat: 'yy/mm/dd'
    }); 
});
```

Will do, you should set it while initializing the datepicker.

Answer (score 0):

Your jQuery `datepicker` should be constructed as seen below. I've added `changeMonth` and `changeYear` to give you added functionality but these can be removed if you don't need them. To attach the `datepicker` to your html, use the `input` element and set it's id, as shown below.

Remember as well, that you need to include both jQuery references below in order to access the library.

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>



<script>
        $(function () {
            $("#datepicker").datepicker({ dateFormat: "yy/mm/dd", changeMonth: true, changeYear: true });
        });
    </script>


<input type="date" id="datepicker" />
```

Working example [Codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/WreLLX)