# Datepicker's dateFormat not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

I have been trying to change the datepicker's format from the default to `yy-mm-dd` but it isn't taking effect. I will add my code below for further reference. Thanks

**HTML:**

```
<input type="text" id="datepicker" name="call_date" class="form-control">
```

And the javascript is below:

**JAVASCRIPT:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd');
    });
</script>
```

The dateFormat seems right but somehow it isn't taking effect and my database is getting inserted with zeroes, i.e `0000-00-00`. Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks

**EDIT: INSERTION QUERY**

```
$date = $_POST['call_date'];
$logqry = "INSERT INTO clinic_log(log_date,log_time,log_caller,log_reason,log_response)VALUES('$date','$time','$caller','$reason','$response')";

$logresult = mysqli_query($conn,$logqry);
```

Comment: how about the code where you insert the `call_date` to your `database`?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1328025/jquery-ui-datepicker-change-date-format

Comment: hi roullie, I have edited the question and have posted the insertion query.

Comment: hi ravneet, how would I call the date variable after that?

Comment: Try changing your date format to `yyyy-mm-dd`.

Comment: Hi David, is the dateFormat working for datepicker, I posted link for the same. Please print $_POST['call_date'] and check is it returning correct value.

Comment: still the same Harry.

Comment: no Ravneet, it is showing the date as `dd/mm/yy` and in datebase it is displaying 0000-00-00

Comment: Please try using formatDate utility, as explained in the post.

Comment: `$( ".selector" ).datepicker({
  dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd"
});`
This is the syntax I used from the link you sent me.

Comment: Can you tell me what you get in `$_POST['call_date'];`

Comment: `19/12/2015` that is the value i am getting and since in db it stores as `yyyy-mm-dd` , It displays `0000-00-00`

Answer (score 3):

your dateformat isn't applied beacuse you missed  closing bracket `'}'` in the date format block,so the format is still the default one i.e. dd/mm/yy, like you mentioned in comment.

change this `datepicker({dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd');` to this `datepicker({dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'});`

here is the [Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ManojSalvi/fczh357w/) after putting barcket.

**JAVASCRIPT** :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'});
    });
</script>
```

Comment: `<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'});
    });
</script>`
Hi, Manoj, Thanks for the answer but it still isn't working the date still shows as `08/12/2015`

Comment: i have given the fiddle , check when you pick the date from datepicker what format it takes in your code????

Comment: I got it working, i changed the format in the default function in the bootstrap-datepicker.js file `format: 'yyyy-mm-dd',` That was the line, it was set to `dd/mm/yyyy` Thanks a lot for all the help guys