# jquery convert date format

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to keep my calendar displays the date which every the user picks. and now my"{{date}}" is in the format like `2016-01-11`. Buy it is keep showing one day before the day I picked. I want it displays like `mm/dd/yyyy`.

I am thinking that I have to convert my date format from `2016-01-11` to `01/11/2016`  but how to accomplish that ?

```
$(function(){
          $("#datepicker").datepicker({
                   onSelect:function(dateText, inst){
                          var day = $.datepciker.formatDate("yy-mm-dd",new Date(dateText));
                          $(location).attr("href","/report_date/" + day + "/");
                   }
          })
          $("#datepicker").datepicker("setDate", new Date("{{date}}"));
})
```

All my directories are named like 2016-10-11, thats why i am using yy-mm-dd

Comment: check this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1328025/jquery-ui-datepicker-change-date-format

Comment: That is not very clear what i should do in here....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i figured it out...

```
' var date = "{{date}}";
  var year = date.substring(0,4);
  var month = date.substring(5,7);
  var day = date.substring(8,10);
  $("#datepicker").datepicker("setDate", month + "/" + day + "/" + year):
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function(){
    $("#datepicker").datepicker({
        onSelect:function(dateText, inst){
            var day = $.datepciker.formatDate("yy-mm-dd",new Date(dateText));
            $(location).attr("href","/report_date/" + day + "/");
        }
    })
    var dateNew = $('#datepicker').datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy' }).val();
    $("#datepicker").datepicker("setDate", dateNew);
})
```