# I have an issue while formatting date in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Actually my problem is that i have to retrieve data in 'dd-MM-yy' format but whenever i try to change 'dateFormat' attribute to 'dd-MM-yy'format,I haven't process further. so please help me to find the solution of this issue..

```
 $("input[name='plannedPrgomStartDate']").datepicker({
                                showOn: "button",
                                buttonImage: "../../IMAGES/EQM/calender_icon.png",
                                buttonImageOnly: true,
                                changeYear: true,
                                changeMonth: true,
                                yearRange: yrRange,
                                dateFormat: 'MM-dd-yy',

                            });

$("input[name='plannedPrgomEndDate']").datepicker({
                                showOn: "button",
                                buttonImage: "../../IMAGES/EQM/calender_icon.png",
                                buttonImageOnly: true,
                                changeYear: true,
                                changeMonth: true,
                                yearRange: yrRange,
                                dateFormat: 'MM-dd-yy',

                            });
```

Here is my code for getting the date value

```
var plannedPrgomStartDate = $('#plannedPrgomStartDate').datepicker().val();
                        var plannedPrgomEndDate = $('#plannedPrgomEndDate').datepicker().val();                        
                        if (Date.parse(plannedPrgomStartDate) >= Date.parse(plannedPrgomEndDate)) {
                            displayErrorFeedback("Start date can not be greater than or equal to end date.");
                                loaderHideShow();
                                 return false;
                        }
```

Comment: Have you searched SO? There a literally hundreds of date formatting questions...

Comment: yes,but didnt get the solution.

Comment: Are you sure none help? None?

Comment: I try many solutions but am not proceed further.Stuck with same thing.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery UI DatePicker - Change Date Format](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1328025/jquery-ui-datepicker-change-date-format)

Comment: thanks paarth ,I already try this solution but am not proceed further

Answer (score 0):

Multiple problems here... :

---

**First**, you access the same component (it's the same, right ?) differently.
First time with name `$("input[name='plannedPrgomStartDate']")`
Second time with id `$('#plannedPrgomStartDate')`
So check it's not a mistake and you really have same name and id.

**Then**, as you get the date value at the datepicker init, you should get no value because none is selected... 
So `Date.parse('')` will give you `NaN`.

Or if the first code part is executed before, you're datepicker is already initialized. So why do you init it again with : `$('#plannedPrgomStartDate').datepicker().val();` ?

`$('#plannedPrgomStartDate').val();` should be suficient.

When this is ok, it should not be a problem with the date format. It should work as expected. See : https://jsfiddle.net/1cym5p6s/