# How to change date picker format from "mm/dd/yy" to "yy/mm/dd"?

Tags: javascript

I need to change the date format to insert it in database but unfortunately changing the dateFormat variable is not working. I have some validations to advance the date against the current date and to make the exceeding date un-clickable.

```
<script>
  $( function() {
    var dateFormat = "mm/dd/yy",
      from = $( "#sd" )
        .datepicker({
             showOn: "button",
            buttonImage: "images/cal-icon.png",
            buttonImageOnly: true,
          minDate: ("setDay, +4"),
          maxDate: "+3M +10D",
          changeMonth: true,
          numberOfMonths: 2
        })
        .on( "change", function() {
          to.datepicker( "option", "minDate", getDate( this ) );
        }),
      to = $( "#ed" ).datepicker({
            showOn: "button",
            buttonImage: "images/cal-icon.png",
            buttonImageOnly: true,
        defaultDate: "+1w",
        changeMonth: true,
        numberOfMonths: 2
      })
      .on( "change", function() {
        from.datepicker( "option", "maxDate", getDate( this ) );
      });

    function getDate( element ) {
      var date;
      try {
        date = $.datepicker.parseDate( dateFormat, element.value );
      } catch( error ) {
        date = null;
      }

      return date;
    }
  } );
  </script>
```

Comment: Where do you pass the `dateFormat` variable into the settings?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery UI DatePicker - Change Date Format](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1328025/jquery-ui-datepicker-change-date-format)

Answer (score 3):

You simply pass this as an option, although this question has been answered many times here on SO.

```
$( ".selector" ).datepicker({
   dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd"
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You're doing it wrong, there's no need to parse the datestring back into some other format to set the `maxDate` and `minDate` options, all you have to do is use the built in `getDate` to get the selected date

```js
$(function() {
    var from = $("#sd").datepicker({
            showOn: "button",
            buttonImage: "images/cal-icon.png",
            buttonImageOnly: true,
            minDate: ("setDay, +4"),
            maxDate: "+3M +10D",
            changeMonth: true,
            numberOfMonths: 2,
            onSelect : function(date, ui) {
             to.datepicker("option", "minDate", $(this).datepicker( 'getDate' ));
            }
        }),
        to = $("#ed").datepicker({
            showOn: "button",
            buttonImage: "images/cal-icon.png",
            buttonImageOnly: true,
            defaultDate: "+1w",
            changeMonth: true,
            numberOfMonths: 2,
            onSelect : function(date, ui) {
             from.datepicker("option", "maxDate", $(this).datepicker( 'getDate' ));
            }
        });
});
```

```html
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<input id="sd">
<br><br>
<input id="ed">
```

When you need the date of the input for something else, all you have to do is call `$("#sd").datepicker( 'getDate' )` etc. and it will return a date object, regardless of the format used in the picker.