# Changing date format of jquery datepicker in asp.net

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I want to change the date format to dd-MM-yyyy currently the date format of my jQuery date pickeris MM-dd-yyyy
below is my code in asp webforms but its not working

```
<link href="../Contents/css/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="../Contents/js/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
    <script src="../Contents/js/jquery-ui.js"></script>
     <script>
        $(function () {
            $("#<%=txtChqDate.ClientID %>").datepicker();
            $("#<%=txtChqDate.ClientID %>").datepicker("option", "showAnim", "drop");
            <%--$("#<%=txtChqDate.ClientID %>").datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy' });   --%>
            $("#format").change(function () {
                $("#<%=txtChqDate.ClientID %>").datepicker("option", "dd-mm-yyyy", $(this).val());
            });
         });
```

Comment: Please check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/1328040/3646606

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the following code in the master page to set it as a default for all datepicker instances, UK has a date format of MM/DD/YYYY

$.datepicker.setDefaults($.datepicker.regional['en-GB']);

Answer (score 0):

Try using below code:

```
var changedDate = $("#<%=txtChqDate.ClientID %>").datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy' }).val();
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are missing the `dateFormat` after `option`

`` $("#`<%=txtChqDate.ClientID %>").datepicker("option", "dateFormat","dd-mm-yyyy", $(this).val()); ``

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 $("#<%=txtChqDate.ClientID %>").datepicker("option", "dateFormat", "dd-M-yy");
```