# Date format showing different using jquery

Tags: jquery, css

I wanna display the dates on my WordPress site like the Picture, where the months with long names come abbreviated.
[image]

My jquery looks like this:

```
jQuery(document).ready( function($){

    var txtFromDate, txtToDate;
  $("#txtFrom").datepicker({
    numberOfMonths: 1,
    onSelect: function(selected) {
      txtFromDate = selected;
      var dt = new Date(selected);
      dt.setDate(dt.getDate() + 1);
      $("#txtTo").datepicker("option", "minDate", dt);
    }
  });
  $("#txtTo").datepicker({
    numberOfMonths: 1,
    onSelect: function(selected) {
      txtToDate = selected;
      var dt = new Date(selected);
      dt.setDate(dt.getDate() - 1);
      $("#txtFrom").datepicker("option", "maxDate", dt);
    }
  });

  $('a#atributo').click(function() {
    // var link = day_1+month_1+year;
     var monthNames = [
        "Jan", "Feb", "Mar",
        "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul",
        "Aug", "Sep", "Oct",
        "Nov", "Dec"
      ];

    var date1 = $("#txtFrom").datepicker('getDate'),
        day_1  = date1.getDate(),  
        month_1 = date1.getMonth() + 1,              
        year_1 =  date1.getFullYear();

    var date2 = $("#txtTo").datepicker('getDate'),
        day_2  = date2.getDate(),  
        month_2 = date2.getMonth() + 1,              
        year_2 =  date2.getFullYear(); 

    var where = $('#selection :selected').text();
    var people = $('#search-pax :selected').val();

    $(this).attr("href", "http://www.lekkeslaap.co.za/akkommodasie-in/"+where+"?q="+where+"&start="+day_1+"+"+monthNames[month_1]+"+"+year_1+'&end='+day_2+'+'+monthNames[month_2]+'+'+year_2+'&pax='+people);
  });
});
```

And for now when I view the site it looks like this:

[image]

How can I change the date format?

I found [this](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-monthNames) in the api documentation but I am struggling to implement

Hope you can help and [here my full pen for it](http://codepen.io/Sidney-Dev/pen/gmyoWM)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery UI DatePicker - Change Date Format](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1328025/jquery-ui-datepicker-change-date-format)

Comment: I do not see the duplicated reference compared to my question

Comment: I see you modified your pen. So a bit duplicated it's ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After the comma where you have "numberOfMonths:1," add this:

```
dateFormat: "d/M/yy"
```

You are welcome to change the slash by dash or nothing

Comment: Appreciate the support

Answer (score 0):

You need to add inside the datepicker options the dateFormat option:

```
dateFormat: "d M yy"
```