# How can I send different date format using juery after calculating with different format?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I am using a form for check-in and check-out dates. For that, I am using [jquery date range picker](https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#date-range)

but it is only allowing me to choose 'mm/dd/yy' date format but I want to submit my form with  'dd M yy' date format. Please help.

```js
$( function() {
    var dateFormat = "mm/dd/yy",
      from = $( "#check_in_date_view" )
        .datepicker({
          defaultDate: "+1w",
          changeMonth: false,
        numberOfMonths: 1
    
        })
        .on( "change", function() {
          to.datepicker( "option", "minDate", getDate( this ) );
        }),
      to = $( "#check_out_date_view" ).datepicker({
        defaultDate: "+1w",
        changeMonth: false,
      numberOfMonths: 1
      })
      .on( "change", function() {
        from.datepicker( "option", "maxDate", getDate( this ) );
      });
 
    function getDate( element ) {
      var date;
      try {
        date = $.datepicker.parseDate( dateFormat, element.value );
      } catch( error ) {
        date = null;
      }
 
      return date;
   
    }
  } );
```

```html
<script src="https://dkgzabag3frbh.cloudfront.net/assets/public-fe4a9982b5d5f02ccf3ae1e703aba2c0.js"></script>
<form class="formtastic" id="booking-form" target="_blank" action="http://example.com" accept-charset="UTF-8" method="get"><input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="&#x2713;" />
<input type="hidden" name="locale" id="locale" value="en" />
<input type="hidden" name="from_widget" id="from_widget" value="true" />
<fieldset class='inputs'>
<ol>
<li class='string'>
<label >Check In Date</label>
<input  type="text" name="check_in_date_view" id="check_in_date_view" class="calendar" data-init-val="null" />
<input type="hidden" name="check_in_date" id="check_in_date"  />
</li>
<li class='string'>
<label>Check Out Date</label>
<input type="text" name="check_out_date_view" id="check_out_date_view" class="calendar" data-init-val="null" />
<input type="hidden" name="check_out_date" id="check_out_date" />
</li>

</ol>
</fieldset>
<fieldset class='actions'>
<ol>


<input name="booking" type="submit" class="check_availability" onClick="return handleClick('')" value="Book Now" />


</ol>
</fieldset>
</form>
```

Comment: [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/) is great for manipulating dates

Comment: Have you seen [this?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1328025/jquery-ui-datepicker-change-date-format)