# How to change the format of JQuery Date Picker to MM/DD/YYYY

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-datepicker

Based on this [link](http://github.com/biohzrdmx)

This where I will go if i wanna change my date format

```
defaults: {
    formatDate: function(date) {
        var formatted = $.datePicker.utils.pad(date.getDate(), 2) + '/' + $.datePicker.utils.pad(date.getMonth() + 1, 2) + '/' + date.getFullYear();
        return formatted;
    },
    parseDate: function(string) {
        var date = new Date();
        var parts = string.match(/(\d{1,2})\/(\d{1,2})\/(\d{4})/);
        if ( parts && parts.length == 4 ) {
            date = new Date( parts[3], parts[2] - 1, parts[1] );
        }
        return date;
    },
    selectDate: function(date) {
        return true;
    },
    limitCenturies: true,
    closeOnPick: true,
    appendTo: null
},
```

How can I make this to MM/DD/YYYY? I tried everything I change it but when Im selecting dates the value goes on different dates

Here is the error

[image]

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1328025/jquery-ui-datepicker-change-date-format

Comment: already check that but still doesnt suits what i needed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://github.com/biohzrdmx/jQuery.DatePicker#custom-date-formats), this should work:

```
    defaults: {
        formatDate: function(date) {
    //var formatted = $.datePicker.utils.pad(date.getDate(), 2) + '/' + $.datePicker.utils.pad(date.getMonth() + 1, 2) + '/' +  date.getFullYear();
            var formatted = $.datePicker.utils.pad(date.getMonth() + 1, 2) + '/' + $.datePicker.utils.pad(date.getDate(), 2) + '/' + date.getFullYear();

            return formatted;
        },
        parseDate: function(string) {
            var date = new Date();

            if ( string ) {
                formatted_date = string.split('/');
                date = new Date( formatted_date[2], formatted_date[0] - 1, formatted_date[1] );
            }

            return date;
        },
        selectDate: function(date) {
            return true;
        },
        limitCenturies: true,
        closeOnPick: true,
        appendTo: null
    }
```

See it in action: [Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/cabrerahector/e8f4zvst/3/).

Comment: this one work and i tried it but everytime i select a date and another the days are moving for example I click the date today the next time I will click another the value of calendar turns to April 2,2020 i will add an image for you to see

Comment: Try creating a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) of your code so we can see it in action. It'll be more helpful than seeing images.

Comment: try this sir sorry if it is not tidy --> https://jsfiddle.net/hc0btwzj/1/

Comment: sir based on your jsfiddle everytime i select a date the month increases by 1

Comment: Sorry, you're right. I've updated the code again to fix that, @NardongBagsik

Answer (score 0):

[Try](http://www.datejs.com/) this out

```
var date = new Date('2014-01-06');
var newDate = date.toString('dd-MM-yy');
```

Comment: `new Date().toString()` don't take any parameters. No need to pass that string.

Comment: var date = new Date('dd-mm-yy')

Comment: I am talking about toString method.