# Can I change the format of date which entered using Local date?

Tags: javascript, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

I want to change the format of the date which I entered using date picker

i want to change it dd-mm-yyyy
but now it's in mm/dd/yyyy

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery UI DatePicker - Change Date Format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1328025/jquery-ui-datepicker-change-date-format)

Comment: Do you want to change this on the Java (server) side or the JavaScript (client) side?

Comment: i want to do this in client(javascript side)

Answer (score 2):

If you have date as string, use this to convert in date and then format it

```
 String sDate1="03/08/1993";  
 Date date1=new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy").parse(sDate1);
```

Use this

```
String pattern = "dd-MM-yyyy";
SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(pattern);

String date = simpleDateFormat.format(date1);
System.out.println(date);
```

to format date in any format

Answer (score 0):

Simply use the following lines of code:

```
$(".datepicker").datepicker({
    dateFormat: "dd-mm-yy",     
});
```

In fact, `yy` serves the purpose of `yyyy` here.