# Convert string of format "mm/dd/yyyy" to Date Obj of format "mm/dd/yyyy" whose typeof should be a Date Object

Tags: javascript, jquery, datetime, jquery-ui-datepicker

I'm getting the date string from sessionStorage and tying to convert into Date object of format MM/DD/YYYY so I can setDate to a datepicker.

## HTML

```
<div id="demo"></div>
<label class="control-label" for="coverageStartDate">
   <input 
    type="text" id="coverageStartDate" 
    data-ng-model="coverageStartDate" 
    class="datepick input-small" 
    title="MM/dd/yyyy" 
    pattern="MM/DD/YYYY">
    <span class="datepick add-on" for="coverageStartDate">
      <i class="far fa-calendar-alt"></i>
    </span>
 </label>
```

## JS

```
var startDate = "01/27/2020";
var coverageStartDate = new Date(startDate);
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = coverageStartDate;

$("#coverageStartDate").datepicker("setDate", coverageStartDate);
```

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/w1g56fzx/4/)**

Comment: Date objects don't have a format to them. You can convert them to a string *and then* format them, but the only information a date object has is the timestamp with a bunch of methods to manipulate it and to display it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [jQuery UI DatePicker - Change Date Format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1328025/jquery-ui-datepicker-change-date-format)

Comment: @VALZ - I tried. But it didn't work for