# jQuery UI datepicker() is ignoring the `format` attribute

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-datepicker

I'm formatting a date with the following code:

```
$('#test-dp-component .input-group.date').datepicker({
                format:'yyyy/mm/dd',
            }).datepicker("setDate",'{{ $module->test }}');
```

So if the date is September 1, 2021, the displayed format is 2021/09/01. However, if I change the format like this:

```
$('#test-dp-component .input-group.date').datepicker({
                format:'mm/dd/yyyy',
            }).datepicker("setDate",'{{ $module->test }}');
```

Then it returns 05/09/1 instead of 09/01/2021. Other formats like mm/yyyy seem to work fine, so why is it freaking out over the mm/dd/yyyy format? Any suggestions?

Comment: What does `{{ $module->test }}` resolve as?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [jQuery UI DatePicker - Change Date Format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1328025/jquery-ui-datepicker-change-date-format)

Comment: 2021-09-01 is what is stored in the DB., but it displays as 05/09/1

Comment: kmoser - no, unfortunately I tried that already. It returns the same 05/09/1

Comment: Okay, so I'm working in Laravel so I decided to use Carbon to format the date in the view. I'm giving up on the javascript, lol

Comment: Hey, did you ever get around to solving this problem?  Does my answer help?

Answer (score 1):

First, the attribute is `dateFormat`, not `format`.  See the example at [Api.jQueryUi.com](https://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-dateFormat):

> `dateFormat`
>
> Default: "mm/dd/yy"
>
> The format for parsed and displayed dates. For a full list of the possible formats see the formatDate function.

Second, the year field is indicate with `yy`, not with (as you would normally think), `yyyy`.

So, you'll want to try:

```
$('#test-dp-component .input-group.date').datepicker({
    dateFormat:'yy/mm/dd',
});
```